# Best way to groupby and join in pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, join, pyspark

Hi I have two dataframe like this:

df_1:

```
id   item   activity
1      2       a
34    14       b
1      2       b
 .     .       .
```

Activity has two uniqe values `a and b`.

df_2:

```
id   item   activity
1      2       c
34    14       c
1      2       c
```

Here activity has all same values `c`

Now I want final df where I have to groupby using `id and item` and get count of unique activities from `df_1 and df_2` and later join them using `id and item`.

df_1_grp (Groupby using `id and item` and get count of activity frequency record):

```
df_1_grp = df_1.groupby("id", "item").agg(f.count(f.when(f.col('activity') == 'a', 1)).alias('a'), f.count(f.when(f.col('activity_type') == 'b', 1)).alias('b'))
```

```
id  item  a   b
1     2   1   1
34   14   0   1
```

df_2_grp (Groupby using `id and item` and just get the count of record as all values in activity is same):

```
df_2_grp = df_2.groupBy("id", "item").count().select('id', 'item', f.col('count').alias('c'))
```

```
id  item  c
1     2   2  
34   14   1
```

And now join them to get final df:

```
df = df_1_grp.join(df_2_grp, on = ['id', 'item'], how = 'inner')
```

Expected Output:

```
id  item  a   b   c
1     2   1   1   2
34   14   0   1   1
```

Now because my dataframe is too big like probably `4 TB or 1 Billion records`. I'm running out of disc storage. Is there more optimized and effecient way of doing it.

Spark Config:

```
spark_config["spark.executor.memory"] = "32G"
spark_config["spark.executor.memoryOverhead"] = "32G"
spark_config["spark.executor.cores"] = "32"
spark_config["spark.driver.memory"] = "8G"

spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors"] = "200"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors"] = "300"
```

Comment: Could you share more information about your spark application configuration, i.e. the no. of executor, core and memory? Also, when you say it's out of disk storage, does it mean error when you do the save action?

Comment: @JonathanLam please check the updated question for spark config, and yess when I try to save it then that problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the spark config to allow for more memory. Can you clarify if it is storage space you're lacking or memory when running the program?

One method to reduce the memory of the  spark session is to save each table to the disk before joining them. This helps runtime and memory usage (or atleast it did for me). Be sure to create new spark sessions after each save.

Comment: You mean I shoudl cache the data before joining?

Answer (score 0):

Join is redundant, much more efficient way is first to `union` the two dataframes and then to perform `groupBy` (union is cheap operation that doesn't require shuffle).

```
my_df = df_1.union(df_2)
my_df.groupby("id", "item").agg(
      f.count(f.when(f.col('activity') == 'a', 1)).alias('a'),
      f.count(f.when(f.col('activity') == 'b', 1)).alias('b'),
      f.count(f.when(f.col('activity') == 'c', 1)).alias('c'),
)
```

Also, for large tables shuffles, as in your case, you need to verify you have adequate values for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and `spark.default.parallelism` - at least 2000 in case of 4TB table (default is 200).